# Simple count and sum functions are not working the way I expect

Tags: c++

I just started to work with functions in C++ so bear with me. I could use any tips you have.

I'm trying to make a program that gives me how many numbers are divisible by 3 from 1 to 10 and it should add up those numbers.

So my code should output:

```
There are 3 numbers divisible by 3, sum of those numbers: 18
```

But it is outputting:

```
There are 1 numbers divisible by 3, sum of those numbers: 9
```

I've been stuck for hours and I don't understand what is missing or what is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Amount_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(int x);
int Sum_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(int y);

int main() {
    int amount_variable, sum_variable;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        amount_variable = Amount_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(i);
        sum_variable = Sum_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(i);
    }
    printf("There are %d numbers divisible by 3, sum of those numbers: %d\n",amount_variable, sum_variable);

    return 0;
}

int Amount_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(int x) 
{
    int amount_of_numbers;

    if (x % 3 == 0) {
        amount_of_numbers++;
    } 

    return amount_of_numbers;
}

int Sum_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(int y)
{
    int sum_of_numbers = 0;

    if (y % 3 == 0) {
        sum_of_numbers += y;
    }

    return sum_of_numbers;
}
```

Comment: It seems that `amount_of_numbers` in `int Amount_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(int)` is uninitialized.

Comment: You are also constantly rewriting `amount_variable` and `sum_variable` inside the loop. So the answer is the same as calling `Amount_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(9) and `Sum_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(9)`.

Comment: Tip: grab a debugger and go through the code line by line with it. Look what happens to the variables. Check where they are defined. Turn your compiler’s warnings to the max to get all possible hints from it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `amount_of_numbers` and `sum_of_numbers` are both stack variables, (which are unitialized). Even if you did zero-initialize them, rather than returning the true total they would only return 1 or 0 for `amount_of_numbers` and the number passed in for the `sum_of_numbers`. For your functions to work as they are you'd need to pass in the total and modify or return the new value.

But lets talk about a better way to do this:

- You know how many multiples of 3 there are between 1 and a given number by dividing it by 3
- You know the sum of these numbers by finding the [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) for that count multiplied by 3

So given a number `const int n` you can find:

- `const auto amount_of_numbers = n / 3`
- `const auto sum_of_numbers = 3 * (amount_of_numbers * (amount_of_numbers + 1) / 2)`

If you need that in a function you could do:

```
pair<int, int> Numbers_Divisible_By_3(const int x) {
    const auto amount_of_numbers = x / 3;
    const auto sum_of_numbers = 3 * (amount_of_numbers * (amount_of_numbers + 1) / 2);

    return { amount_of_numbers, sum_of_numbers };
}
```

If you wanted to find the results on numbers between 1 and 10 you could simply call: `Numbers_Divisible_By_3(10)`.

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/GpsLh3)

Answer (score 0):

all variables declared inside a function only have a scope pertinent inside the function. Outside it has no sense even if the variable name is the same somewhere else.
So amount_of_numbers and sum_of_numbers must be passed as reference to the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Amount_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(int x, int& amount_of_numbers);
void Sum_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(int y, int& sum_of_numbers);

int main() {
    int amount_variable=0, sum_variable=0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        Amount_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(i, amount_variable);
        Sum_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(i, sum_variable);
    }
    printf("There are %d numbers divisible by 3, sum of those numbers: %d\n", amount_variable, sum_variable);

    return 0;
}

void Amount_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(int x, int & amount_of_numbers)
{

    if (x % 3 == 0) {
        amount_of_numbers++;
    }
}

void Sum_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(int y, int & sum_of_numbers)
{

    if (y % 3 == 0) {
        sum_of_numbers += y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you have to change this one `x % 3 == 0` into `x / 3 == 0` 
(change the mode(%) to division(/) )

```
int Amount_of_Numbers_Divisible_By_3(int x) 
{
    int amount_of_numbers;

    if (x / 3 == 0) {
        amount_of_numbers++;
    } 

    return amount_of_numbers;
}
```

In this case divisible numbers 3 (there are: 3,6,9);
             sum: 3+6+9=18

Comment: 6%3 == 0 ok 6 can be divided by zero. 6/3 = 2 and also 7/3=2 and 8/3=2 what does that tell us… not much. So % is the way to go